# The same iptables NAT commands works in ubuntu 18.04 and 22.04 but not in 20.04

Tags: networking, iptables

My layout is:

[image: layout]

My goal is to ping the Internet from eth0 through enp45s0 and wlo1.
The commands below works well in ubuntu 18.04, 22.04 but not in 20.04(unable ping the Internet like google.com, DNS).

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1  
$ sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlo1 -j MASQUERADE   
$ sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp45s0 -j ACCEPT
```

Instead of using the commands above, I have to use the commands below to make it work in 20.04.

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1  
sudo iptables -F 
sudo iptables -F -t nat 
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wlo1 -i enp45s0 -s 192.168.1.10/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING 
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlo1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Could someone help me understand the reason why I have to make these changes?

Hi Doug Smythies,
I do not have 18.04 and 22.04 environment currently, so we may focus on the reason that the first set of commands not working in 20.04. Please check the default iptable seetings below.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
$ sudo iptables -xvnL
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 357 packets, 265671 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 
 Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 49 packets, 4116 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       49     4116 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       49     4116 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
        0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
        0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
        0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
        0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 
 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 370 packets, 36494 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 
 Chain DOCKER (1 references)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 
 Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
        0        0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/ 0
       49     4116 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 
 Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
        0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
        0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 
 Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       49     4116 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
------------------------------------------------------------------
sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL
 Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 57 packets, 4958 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
        1      254 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
 
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 254 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 
 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 68 packets, 5655 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
        0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
 
 Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 68 packets, 5655 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
        0        0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
 
 Chain DOCKER (2 references)
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
        0        0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
------------------------------------------------------------------
$ route -n
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
 0.0.0.0         192.168.223.114 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
 169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp45s0
 172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
 192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp45s0
 192.168.223.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What iptables rules exist before you make your changes and what default policies are being used? Do `sudo iptables -xvnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL`. What default routes?

Comment: @Doug Smythies Please find the info in the edited post.

Comment: You have a default policy of DROP for your FORWARD chain, so you need to provide a return path which you are doing via the  ESTABLISHED,RELATED rule.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. It helps a lot.